# What are the supported filter operations on Azure Resource Group list

Tags: azure, odata, azure-resource-group

I'm trying to find a resource group that has a partial name match.

I'm trying something like:
`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<sub ID>/resourcegroups?api-version=2020-10-01&%24filter=substringof(Name%2C%20'<something>')`

but I keep getting:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidFilterInQueryString",
    "message": "Invalid $filter 'substringof(Name, '<something>')' specified in the query string."
  }
}
```

I've been trying it out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resource-groups/list#code-try-0

But sadly cannot find the list of filters that I can use in this rest call.  All of the string ones from here don't seem to work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/using-filter-expressions-in-odata-uris

Does anyone know where to find the list?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Resource Manager (ARM) does not support the substringof function in the $filter query for resource groups.

If you need to filter resource groups by a partial name match, you can have retrieve all resource groups and then filter them client-side.

1. ***Retrieve All Resource Groups***:

   For example, using Azure CLI:

   ```bash
   az group list --output json
   ```
2. ***Filter Client-Side***:
   using the Azure CLI and `jq` (a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor), you can:

   ```bash
   az group list --output json | jq '.[] | select(.name | contains("<something>"))'
   ```

Comment: Thanks, that was my backup plan but I'm curious if there's a published list of what it does support for future reference